Travelling back to the UK from the US with a slightly damaged EU passport
In summary, I'm temporarily living in the US for the summer and my EU passport has got minor damage: a small tear in the page immediately after the page with the personal details/photo ID. Similar questions have been asked here, but my case has some unique features. I'm already abroad. More specifically, I'm in the US with an EU passport and my return flight is to the UK.
I have a visa stamped on my passport. All my visa documentation is associated to the passport. To clarify, it's a US visa. I don't need a visa in the UK, as I  hold the pre-settled status there (approximately equivalent to the green card in the US).
Cover and backcover are intact, page with personal information and signature is also intact, visas are intact, empty pages reserved for visas are intact. The page with the damage is the page immediately after the page with personal information.
The way it currently looks, if you don't actively stare at the tear or try moving the page,  you don't see that there's a tear, you see a wrinkle.
The damage started as a wrinkle. Somehow, when closing the cover of my passport the wrinkle got worse, and it ended up with a tear near the side. None of the page has been lost or detached.
I need to go back to the UK in a few months, where I normally live, but I'm not a UK citizen. I'll be traveling to the UK via Dublin.
I asked my consulate of reference, and they advised me not to do anything and just keep using my passport.
Still, I'm feeling a bit paranoid about being denied boarding, and I looked for appointments for getting a new passport to my consulate of reference, and it feels very tight time-wise to get a passport before my return date, assuming they agreed to emit a new one. Earliest appointment I could find would be for the end of July, and then there's August. In my country nothing gets done during August. And the consulate itself can't emit passports, they need to send the requests to the headquarters in Europe and then get it send it back.
If I initiated the process for getting a new passport, I could be months without a passport and without my visa in the US. Not looking forward to that. And then praying for the new passport to arrive in time.
My return flight is associated with my current passport. I can't change it as I didn't buy it personally.
My one goal is being able to leave the US and get to the UK. Once there I'll have way more time and flexibility to replace the passport.
I hold the pre-settled status in the UK, which means that technically I should be able to get into the country with my EU national ID.
I'd greatly appreciate any advice.

In the UK, assuming you are landing at one of the major airports, you usually would just put your passport in the automated gates and no human would look at it (assuming your pre-settled status is associated with your passport).

Anecdotal evidence. I returned to the UK (EU citizen) 3 days ago on the Eurostar. On the way to the train station I got caught in a major downpour, leaving my passport somewhat damp. I got a glare from French border control and a shrug from the Brits, and both just used the plastic bit to verify my actual eligibility to board the train.

Since you are entering the Common Travel Area through Dublin (Republic of Ireland, an EU country) all you need is proof of your EU citizenship. Most airlines should be aware of that.

Story today on BBC News about a woman refused boarding by TUI at Gatwick for her vacation flight to Mexico because of slight damage to her passport (pic included) which she had not previously been aware of. She had to re-book with British Airways at a cost of £1200 ($1520 USD). BA saw no problems with her passport at boarding. Following a complaint TUI are refunding that cost. She had very recently come back from Morocco with no trouble of this kind. So be prepared for inconvenience.
